# Launching firefox on 16.04 causes system freeze

Tags: firefox

I have an old Compac SR5130NX with AMD Athlon 64x2 cpu that I had installed Ubuntu 12.04, A couple days ago, I updated to 14.04.5. After the installation, I started getting scrambled video and a frozen system when trying to launch Firefox. I then updated to 16.04, and after a day of trouble-free operation it is starting to do it again. It doesn't happen all the time, but when it does, my only option is to do a hard power down. What is going on?
*Update: This symptom is happening not only with firefox, but other apps as well. I am starting to get the idea that it is video related. I have Openscad on this machine, and it seems to cause a lock-up whenever I try to do a 3D  rendering. Is it possible the onboard video in this MB is what is causing the problems?

Comment: Please [edit] and add information regarding hardware specs and/or brand/model. PS: It's **Compaq**.

Comment: Also, if there is a consistent error with firefox, open a terminal window CTRL+ALT+t and run firefox from the command line.  It may give additional information on what is going on.

Comment: Maybe faulty add-ons in Firefox...